# How to hide element by id using @media?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I am using @media queries in CSS, how set up display:none for specific @media size and override all bootstrap media setup?

My html:

```
<div id="top" class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container"> 
         Menu
        </div>
    </div>
```

My css:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px){
#top{
    dislay:none;
    }
}
```

Where I am wrong?

Comment: Its a typo...Try 'display:none;'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typo mistake in your css replace `display:none`

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px){
  #top{
    display:none;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You just wrote wrong. It's `display`, not `dislay`.

If is interesting to keep the structure where the object is, but don't show it, consider using `visibility:hidden` instead of `display:none`.